# 1+1 = 10, 1+2 = 3

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, base-conversion, binary

Write a function or program than can do simple arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division) in both base 10 and base 2.

The function will take a mathematical expression as input, and output the correct result in the correct base. The input will be `n` numbers separated by one or several operators (`+ - * /`).

If all input values contain only 0 and 1, all values are considered to be binary. If at least one digit is `2-9`, all values are considered to be base 10.

**Rules:**

- You can assume there will only be one operator between numbers (`10*-1` will not appear)
- You can assume there will be no parentheses.
- Normal operator precedence (try the expression in the google calculator if you're in doubt).
- You can not assume there will only be integers
- There will be no leading zeros in input or output
- You can assume only valid input will be given
- You can assume all input values are positive (but the minus operator may make negative output possible, `1-2=-1` and `10-100=-10`)
- REPL is not accepted
- You may choose to take the input as separate arguments, or as a single argument, but the input *has* to be in the correct order.

  - I.e. you may represent `1-2` with the input arguments `1`, `-`, `2`, but not `1`, `2`, `-`.
- You must accept the symbols `+ - * /` in the input, not `plus`, `minus` etc.
- You must support floating point values (or up to the maximum limit of your language, however supporting only integers is not accepted).
- `eval` is accepted

**Examples:**

```
1+1
10

1010+10-1
1011

102+10-1
111

1+2+3
6

10*10*10
1000

11*11*11
11011

10*11*12+1
1321

10.1*10.1
110.01

20.2*20.2
408.04

10/5
2

110/10
11

Also accepted (optional line or comma-separated input):
10
+
10
-
1
11    <-- This is the output
```

This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes will win.

Comment: In the case of `110/10`, is `11.0` acceptable?

Comment: @isaacg yes, that's ok :-)

Comment: The downvote... why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Japt, <s>77</s> <s>72</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> <s>62<sup>*</sup></s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 51 bytes

```
OvUf"[2-9]" ?U:"({Ur"[\\d.]+""º$&e14+P n2 /2pE¹"})¤
```

Explanation (more or less the same as for the JS answer):

```
Ov                       //eval...
  Uf"[2-9]"              //if input contains the digits 2 to 9
    U:                   //then it's base 10, just compute
    Ur"[\\d.]+"          //otherwise replace all the numbers
    "º$&e14+P n2 /2pE¹"  //with their base 10 equivalents
                         //I.e., take every number, multiple by 10^14, convert to
                         //base 10 and divide by 2^14
                         // º and ¹ are multiple brackets
    ¤                    //means "s2", i.e. convert the result to binary
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=T3ZVZiJbMi05XSIgP1U6Iih7VXIiW1xcZC5dKyIiuiQmZTE0K1AgbjIgLzJwRbkifSmk&input=IjEwLjEqMTAuMSI=)

---

<sup>* didn't divide properly</sup>

Comment: As of [5 days ago](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt/commit/756d82dfdb7eba5aff99c84dcece6b54ac42ad26), JS's `eval` is assigned to `Ox`. I'll see if it can be further shortened.

Comment: @Eth Thanks, this saves 5 bytes.

Comment: 5 more bytes saved: ``OxUf"[2-9]" ?U:`({Ur"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?""(($&e14+P).n(2)/16384)"}).s(2)`` It's probably possible to make it generate Japt code instead of JS, then use `Ov` to evaluate that.

Comment: Yup, 62 bytes :) ``OvUf"[2-9]" ?U:Ur"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?""~~[$&e14+P n2 /16384]" +" s2`` The `~~[...]` is necessary because [mismatched parentheses in a string mess with the transpiler](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt/issues/11).

Comment: @Eth Heh, I've come with another 62 bytes solution thanks to the Ov

Comment: `16384` => `2pE` ;)

Comment: @Ethprod Exactly!

Comment: 51: `OvUf"[2-9]" ?U:"({Ur"[\\d.]+""º$&e14+P n2 /2pE¹"})¤`

Comment: @Eth yep, shortening this too, but didn't think about `¤`

Comment: (sorry for late) You can save 1 byte on using `%d` instead of `\\d` (PS: This is 51 chars, but 54 bytes due to use of multibyte characters)

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>87</s> <s>97<sup>1</sup></s> <s>100<sup>2</sup></s> <s>106<sup>3</sup></s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>98</s> <s>100<sup>4</sup></s> <s>93</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
e=>eval(e.match`[2-9]`?e:`(${e.replace(/[\d.]+/g,"('0b'+$&e14)/16384")}).toString(2)`)
```

Demo + explanation:

```js
function c(e){
    return eval(                        
      e.match`[2-9]`?                  //check if there are numbers 2 to 9
        e:                             //if there're, just compute the result
        "("+                           
         e.replace(                    //otherwise replace...
           /[\d.]+/g,                  //any number...
           "(('0b'+$&e14)/16384)"    //...with itself converted to base 10
         )
        +").toString(2)"               //compute the result and convert it to binary
    )
}

document.write(
   c("1.1*1.1")+"<br>"+
   c("1010+10-1")+"<br>"+
   c("102+10-1")+"<br>"+
   c("1+2+3")+"<br>"+
   c("10*10*10")+"<br>"+
   c("11*11*11")+"<br>"+
   c("10*11*12+1")+"<br>"+
   c("10.1*10.1")+"<br>"+
   c("20.2*20.2")+"<br>"+
   c("10/5")+"<br>"+
   c(`10
      +
      10
      -
      1`)
)
```

---

<sup>1 - forgot about floats</sup>
<sup>2 - again floats problem: parseInt floors binary so I have to multiply by 1e14 and then divide by 16384</sup>
<sup>3 - hope that's achieved the given task, now start to golf :D</sup>
<sup>4 - there was a bug with dividing</sup>

Comment: 106^3 bytes? That's more than a million!

Comment: @Eth I knew such a comment was coming ;D

Comment: You can change `e.match(/[2-9]/g)` to `e.match\`[2-9]\``.

Comment: @nicael `('0b'+$&*1e14)/1638` this *should* work but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Hah, here it is :) Seems to work properly.

Comment: `/\d+(\.\d+)?/g` => `/[\d.]+/g`?

Comment: @Eth Haha, didn't even think that there're not so many characters that the regex should be that strict, nice solution :)

Comment: @nicael, very nice. It might have been unclear in the question text, but the input with line breaks was optional in case your language/program/function couldn't handle a one-line input. I don't know if you're using extra chars to support the last example, but if you do: It's not necessary, so you can shorten your code a bit =)

Comment: @Stewie No extra chars, that's a feature of JavaScript when using template strings. Note how the last example is wrapped in `\`` instead of `"` :)

Comment: Hmm, weird syntax highlighting bug: in the explanation line that starts with a regex, the parser thinks the *second* slash starts the regex, not the first. Thus, the comment is black instead of grey.

Comment: @Eth Yeah, noticed this.

Answer (score 5):

## Jolf, 31 bytes, noncompeting

I added a decent amount of functions inspired by this challenge, and, as thus, it is considered noncompeting. I'm happy because I finally implemented unary functions (like `(H,S,n)=>val` in ES6, but are supported in ES5!)

```
? hi"[2-9]"~eiB~epT mpvid|m'H2H
? hi"[2-9]"                     if the input contains any of 2..9
           ~ei                   evaluate i (implicitly print)
                                else
                   _mpvid        map the input split into number groups
                          m'H2    to H as a binary float
                         |    H   (or keep H, if that doesn't work)
                 pT              join by spaces
               ~e                evaluate
              B                  convert to binary (implicitly print)
```

[Test suite](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=PyBoaSJbMi05XSJ-ZWlCfmVwVCBtcHZpZHxtJ0gySA&input=MSsxCgoxMDEwKzEwLTEKCjEwMisxMC0xCgoxKzIrMwoKMTAqMTAqMTAKCjExKjExKjExCgoxMCoxMSoxMisxCgoxMC4xKjEwLjEKCjIwLjIqMjAuMgoKMTAvNQoKMTEwLzEw), [Try your own input](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=PyBoaSJbMi05XSJ-ZWlCfmVwVCBtcHZpZHxtJ0gySA), [or manually set the input](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b2kiWU9VUiBRVUVSWSBIRVJFIgo_IGhpIlsyLTldIn5laUJ-ZXBUIG1wdmlkfG0nSDJI).

Comment: Your code says "hi" to its readers!

Comment: Wow. I didn't notice that! :D

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, 60 bytes

```
[ -z `tr -dc 2-9<<<$1` ]&&s='obase=2;ibase=2;';bc -l<<<$s$1
```

Example Run:

```
$ ./bin_dec_add.sh 1+1
10
$ ./bin_dec_add.sh 1+2
3
```

Comment: @Pietu1998 `dc` would require reverse polish ordering of the operations, which is disallowed by the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## 2, 46 chars / 72 bytes

```
ë(ïđ/[2-9]⎞?ï:`(⦃ïē/[\d.]+⌿,↪(Յ+$*ḊⁿḎ)/Ẁ²)})ⓑ`
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=10.1*10.1&code=%C3%AB%28%C3%AF%C4%91%2F%5B2-9%5D%E2%8E%9E%3F%C3%AF%3A%60%28%E2%A6%83%C3%AF%C4%93%2F%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%E2%8C%BF%2C%E2%86%AA%28%D5%85%2B%24*%E1%B8%8A%E2%81%BF%E1%B8%8E%29%2F%E1%BA%80%C2%B2%29%7D%29%E2%93%91%60)</kbd>

## Explanation

```
ë(ïđ/[2-9]⎞?ï:`(⦃ïē/[\d.]+⌿,↪(Յ+$*ḊⁿḎ)/Ẁ²)})ⓑ` // implicit: ï=input, Ḋ=10, Ḏ=14, Ẁ=128
ë(                                              // eval
  ïđ/[2-9]⎞?                                    // does ï have 2-9?
            ï                                   // if so, eval input
             :                                  // else, eval:
              `(⦃ïē/[\d.]+⌿,                    // replace the binary numbers
                                                // with their base 10 equivalents:
                            ↪(Յ+                // translates to `0b`
                                $*ḊⁿḎ           // matched number * 10^14
                                     )/Ẁ²       // divided by 128^2
                                         )})ⓑ` // converted to binary
                                                // implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 107 bytes

```powershell
param($e)iex(("{0}String($($e-replace'(\d+)','{0}Int32("$1",2)'),2)"-f'[Convert]::To'),$e)[$e-match'[2-9]']
```

## Ungolfed

```
param($e) # Accept single argument
Invoke-Expression # Eval
  ( # Expression, resulting in an array of 2 elements
    (
      "{0}String( # Binary
        $( # Inline subexpression
          $e -replace'(\d+)', '{0}Int32("$1",2)'
          # "1010+10-1" becomes "{0}Int32("1010",2)+{0}Int32("10",2)-{0}Int32("1",2)"
        )
      ,2)"
      -f '[Convert]::To'
      # "{0}Int32("1010",2)+{0}Int32("10",2)-{0}Int32("1",2)" becomes
        "[Convert]::ToString([Convert]::ToInt32("1010",2)+[Convert]::ToInt32("10",2)-[Convert]::ToInt32("1",2),2)"
    ),
      $e # Plain
    )
    [$e-match'[2-9]'] # Return 1st element of array if regex matches, else 0
```

## Example

```
PS > .\Calc.ps1 1010+10-1
1011

PS > .\Calc.ps1 20.2*20.2
408,04
```